# inflateException binary xml file line #9?

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio

Im trying to build android application I have menu that starts another activity. But my app is crashing when click the menu. Here is my xml file

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".Index">

    <Button
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="250dp"
        android:layout_width="65dp"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:id="@+id/time1"
        android:background="@drawable/time"
        />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/time1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="250dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="Dars Jadvali" />

    <Button
        android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="130dp"
        android:id="@+id/conf1"
        android:layout_width="85dp"
        android:layout_height="55dp"
        android:background="@drawable/video"
        />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/conf1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="130dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        android:text="Video Dars" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

this is menu xml that I call for Inflate method

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@+id/bosh"
        android:title="Bosh Sahifa">
    </item>

    <item
        android:id="@+id/eng"
        android:title="English"
        >
    </item>

    <item android:id="@+id/exit"
        android:title="Chiqish">
    </item>
</menu>
```

this is a java class that is crashing when try to open it

```
package com.example.narxoz;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.InflateException;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;

public class IndexUz extends AppCompatActivity {
    UserSessionManager session;
    Button time, conf;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_index_uz);

        time = findViewById(R.id.time1);
        conf = findViewById(R.id.conf1);

        time.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent7 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), IndexTabUz.class);
                startActivity(intent7);
            }
        });

        conf.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent8 = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Video_Conference2.class);
                startActivity(intent8);
            }
        });

        session = new UserSessionManager(getApplicationContext());

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
       try {
           MenuInflater inflater = getMenuInflater();
           inflater.inflate(R.menu.drawermenuuz, menu);
       }catch (InflateException e){

       }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        switch(item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.bosh:
                Intent intent3 = new Intent(this, IndexUz.class);
                this.startActivity(intent3);
                break;
            case R.id.eng:
                Intent intent = new Intent(this, Index.class);
                this.startActivity(intent);
                break;
            case R.id.exit:
                session.logoutUser();
                System.exit(0);
                finish();
                break;
            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }

        return true;
    }

    /*
    public void OnTimetable1(View v){
        Intent intent7 = new Intent(this, IndexTabUz.class);
        this.startActivity(intent7);

    }

    public void OnConferecne1(View v){
        Intent intent8 = new Intent(this, Video_Conference2.class);
        this.startActivity(intent8);
    }
*/
}
```

and this is error app giving:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.narxoz/com.example.narxoz.Index}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class Button
 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2485)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2545)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1100(ActivityThread.java:151)
 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1396)
 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:157)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5601)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:774)
 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:652)
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class Button
 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:543)
 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:427)
 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:374)
 at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:555)
 at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:161)
 at com.example.narxoz.Index.onCreate(Index.java:17)
 at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:6355)
 at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1108)
 at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2438)
 ... 9 more
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #9: Error inflating class Button
 at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:786)
 at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:708)
 at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:839)
 at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:802)
 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:519)
 ... 17 more
Caused by: android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource "com.example.narxoz:drawable/time" (7f0700ac) is not a Drawable (color or path): TypedValue{t=0x1/d=0x7f0700ac a=-1 r=0x7f0700ac}
 at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawableForCookie(Resources.java:2646)
 at android.content.res.Resources.loadDrawable(Resources.java:2580)
 at android.content.res.MiuiResources.loadDrawable(MiuiResources.java:398)
 at android.content.res.TypedArray.getDrawable(TypedArray.java:872)
 at android.view.View.<init>(View.java:3963)
 at android.widget.TextView.<init>(TextView.java:680)
 at android.widget.Button.<init>(Button.java:109)
 at android.widget.Button.<init>(Button.java:105)
 at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton.<init>(AppCompatButton.java:72)
 at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatButton.<init>(AppCompatButton.java:68)
 at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createButton(AppCompatViewInflater.java:192)
 at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatViewInflater.createView(AppCompatViewInflater.java:111)
 at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.createView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:1407)
 at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.onCreateView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:1457)
 at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:750)
 ... 21 more
```

could anyone help ? thanks in advance

Comment: I think `drawable/time` has problem , change it to another `drawable` and test it again.

Comment: Resources$NotFoundException :  means you put your resouce in other drawable folder like drawable-v21 ...just check it and put into main folder